# Can't get correct output from created class (wage + commission calculator)

Tags: java, class, calculator, system.out

So I'm writing a program that is supposed to take a person's wage ($7.25) and add their commission, then spit out the total.  I input all the requested info and I get 0.0 for the result, which is obviously wrong.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!!
HERE'S WHAT I HAVE IN THE DRIVER CLASS:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double hours, sales, total;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
    Wages emp1 = new Wages();

    System.out.println("Please enter the hours worked: ");
    hours = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please the amount of sales: ");
    sales = input.nextDouble();




    System.out.println("Your total pay check wages are: " + df.format(emp1.getEverything()));
```

}

AND HERE'S THE WAGES CLASS I CREATED:

```
    public class Wages {

private double PAY_RATE = 7.25;
public double sales, commission, total;
public int hours;

public Wages(){
}
public Wages(double rate,double sales, double total, double commission, int hours){
    this.sales = sales;
    this.total = total;
    this.PAY_RATE = rate;
    this.commission = commission;
    this.hours = hours;
}

public double getSales(){
    return sales;
}

public double getCommission(){
    if(sales >= 1.00 && sales <= 99.99){
        commission = (sales * 0.05);
        return commission;
    }
    else if(sales >= 100.00 && sales <= 299.99){
        commission = (sales * 0.10);
        return commission;
    }
    else if(sales >= 300.00){
        commission = (sales * 0.15);
        return commission;
    }
    return commission;
}
public double getEverything(){
    total = (PAY_RATE * hours) + commission;
    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably because you never set the `Wages`'s hours or sales.

Comment: So do I create those two set methods in my wages class? And call them in the driver class?

Comment: That's one way, yes.

Comment: Also in getEverything() you should call getComission() instead of comission, otherwise it won't be set either

Comment: What would be another way of doing this?

Comment: you dont add hours/sales into emp1 at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a constructor that takes sales and hours, but you didn't use that constructor and instead called default.

So sales and hours have no values.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do it, I'd change up your Wages class to include this:

```
public double hours; //You're taking a double for their input, so replace the int

public Wages(double hours, double sales){
    this.sales = sales;
    this.hours = hours;
}

//...

public double getEverything(){
    total = (PAY_RATE * hours) + getCommission();
    return total;
}
```

and use this in the driver:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the hours worked: ");
hours = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Please the amount of sales: ");
sales = input.nextDouble();

Wages emp1 = new Wages(hours, sales);
```

Comment: why would I put the public double getEverything in the driver class?  Is that necessary?

Comment: And thank you all for your help and time. I have to leave for work right now but I'll check back later with progress. Cheers

Comment: Woops, added that to the end of the wrong section, it should definitely be part of the wages class